# Freemarker parse a String as Json

Tags: freemarker

Probably it's not possible,
but I would like to transform a json string in a map with freemarker

ex:

```
<#assign test = "{\"foo\":\"bar\", \"f\":4, \"text\":\"bla bla\"}">
```

and be able to get the **text** key from this string

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `?eval_json` (requires FreeMarker 2.3.31):

```
<#-- Using '...' instead of "..." for convenience: no need for \" escapes this way. -->
<#assign test = '{"foo":"bar", "f":4, "text":"bla bla"}'>
<#assign m = test?eval_json>

${m.foo}  <#-- prints: bar -->

<#-- Dump the whole map: -->
<#list m as k, v>
  ${k} => ${v}
</#list>
```

Before 2.3.31, `?eval` was popular for this purpose, but that actually expects FreeMarker expressions. That's a problem because it doesn't support `null`, or `\uXXXX` escapes (so parsing of such JSON will fail). Also it can be a security problem, because it supports accessing variables, and calling methods/functions, while JSON doesn't.

Comment: what if `test` has a null value? or undefined?

Comment: You mean what if `test` is the string "null" or "undefined"? Neither is a valid FTL expression (though `null` will be sometimes in the future), so you need to check for them explicitly. `undefined` is not a valid JSON expression either. Also updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: This is not going to work if you have UNICODE in your json.

Comment: @Ahmed You mean `\u<code>` escapes. Note that `?eval_json` does support that (it was added years after your comment).

Answer (score 5):

[freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html)

in code:

```
// a class to parse Json, just add this method to your rendered template data
// with data.put("JsonParser", new FreemarkerJsonParser()); 
// or in shared variables http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_config_sharedvariables.html
public class FreemarkerJsonParser implements TemplateMethodModel{
    @Override
    public Object exec(List args) throws TemplateModelException {
        return new Gson().fromJson(s, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType());((String) args.get(0));
    }
}
```

in the template:

```
<#assign map = JsonParser("{\"foo\":\"bar\", \"f\":4, \"text\":\"bla bla\"}")>
${map.text}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to define/implement a [template](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html) that reads JSON.

Comment: what about a lazy index_of and removing the bound `"` :P

Comment: Can you tell me if it can be done with a method call http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_methodcall, for ex calling <#assign map = jsponparse(mystring)>

Comment: it's ok found this doc http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_datamodel_method.html more useful