# Escape string in a JSON object

Tags: json, escaping, freemarker

We use Freemarker to transform one JSON to another. The input JSON is something like this:

```
{"k1": "a", "k2":"line1. \n line2"}
```

Post using the Freemarker template, the JSON is converted to:

```
{ \n\n "p1": "a", \n\n "p2": "line1. \n line2"}
```

Here is the logic we use to do the transformation

```
final Map<String, Object> input = JsonConverter.convertFromJson(input, Map.class);
final Template template = freeMarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("Template1.ftl");
final Writer out = new StringWriter();
template.process(input, out);
out.flush();
final String newlineFilteredResult = new JSONObject(out.toString).toString();
```

The conversion to JSON object fails due to a newline character inside a string for key k2 and gives the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at ...
```

I tried using the following but nothing works:

1. JSONObject.quote 
2. JSONValue.escape 
3. out.toString().replaceAll("[\n\r]+", "\\n");
I get the following exception due to the newline characters at the beginning as well:

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Could someone please point me in the correct direction.

Comment: In the template output, how do those `\n`-s get there between the key-value pairs? Are they literally there at all, or are those real line breaks (in which case, are the `\n`-s inside the string literals also real line breaks)? Can you show your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

After further clarification from OP he had `"${key}": "${value}"` in his freemarker template and `${value}` could contain line brakes. The solution in this case is to use `${value?json_string}`.

Comment: The example that I gave was just a sample. There is no consistency in the number of newline characters between each pair. Also there can be multiple newline characters inside the string. 
The string (value) actually takes a summary or a description of a product in some cases. Hence, there is no restriction on the newline characters provided by the user.

Comment: And what can happen with them? Can they be removed and only the one inside the json value needs to become a litteral `\n` or do they need to remain? Also instead of solving this with regex another option is to fix your template. @Vipul

Comment: We need to keep the newline with the string as it as. This is to ensure that the user experience is not changed. 
I was trying to fix the output of the template using some other Writer but am unable to do so. What do you mean by fixing the template?

Comment: Fixing it in such a way that it won't output illegal json. (that it fill output literal `\n` inside json values).

Comment: I agree to this. 
Inside the template, in case of strings, we use the following:
<#elseif value?is_string>
      "${key}": "${value}"
In this case, if the value contains newline, it is not converted to a valid JSON. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Got it. ?json_string solves the problem. Thanks a lot for your effort.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431223/convert-string-to-json-in-freemarker

Comment: `${value?json_string}`

Comment: Thanks. Do you want add another answer?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.32 you can write `"${key}": ${value?c}` instead of `"${key}": "${value}"`, because if the left-side of `?c` is a string, now instead of failing, it **quotes and escapes the string**. Thus you don't even have to know if the left-side is a number/boolean, which must not be quoted (and `?c` won't quote them), or a string, which must be quoted, as it's automatic.

Also, if the left-value is known to be missing/`null` sometimes, them `?cn` will handle that case by printing a `null` literal.

Also, check out the `c_format` setting for best results, but by default string formatting is JSON compatible, so using `?c` will be an improvement even without setting that.