# How to get an object from a list of object in Freemarker

Tags: json, freemarker

I am trying to get one object returned from a list of objects;

`list = [{"name":"Joe","id":1},{"name":"Fred","id":2}]`

I want to output the object exactly like the format below;

`{"name":"Joe","id":1}`

It throws errors when I want to access the object in its entirety;

`${list?first} -> Error: Expected a string or something automatically...`

Testing this on https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ but I can't seem to be able to extract the full first object, whilst accessing a property from that object works fine..?

I understand that this is somewhat of an odd use case to display the object like that. I need it for a business program that uses freemarker and I want to assign the object back into a variable, which accepts this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show values that can be converted to String as error (below) suggest

```
<#assign item = list[0]>
${item.name} ${item.id}
```

> ```
> For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to 
> string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a 
> sequence (ArrayList wrapped into f.t.DefaultListAdapter):
> ==> list  [in nameless template at line 1, column 3]
> ```

You can check [freemarker parse a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087436/freemarker-parse-a-string-as-json/13090357#13090357) answers, for executing similar as:

> ```
> <#assign array = '[{"name":"Joe","id":1},{"name":"Fred","id":2}]'> 
> <#assign object = array?eval[0]> 
> <#list object?keys as key>"${key}":"${object[key]}"
> </#list>
> ```

Comment: I can do the same with ${list?first.name}, but how to retrieve the full object like {"name":"Joe","id":1} ? The object properties are not always the same, so I just want to have the full object.

Comment: @Bastiaan you get it in first line  `<#assign item = list[0]>`

Comment: I understand that items contains the first object. However I still cannot output exactly {"name":"Joe","id":1} in any way? When I do the assign and then after that ${item} I get the exact same error. Have elaborated a bit more in the question to explain the use case

Comment: @Bastiaan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087436/freemarker-parse-a-string-as-json/13090357#13090357

Comment: Thanks! I have it working, do you want to update your answer with this, so I can accept it as the answer?
<#assign array = '[{"name":"Joe","id":1},{"name":"Fred","id":2}]'>
<#assign object = array?eval[0]>
<#list object?keys as key>"${key}":"${object[key]}"</#list>