# How to display array, json directly in freemarker template?

Tags: freemarker

Problem arises when data coming to template is not fixed in nature, for example we were trying to show headers of an API call snippet of which looks like this:

```
"pragma":"no-cache","via":"1.1 vegur","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","CF-Cache-Status":"HIT","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","NEL":{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800},"Report-To":{"endpoints":[{"url":"https://url?s="}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freemarker parse a String as Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087436/freemarker-parse-a-string-as-json)

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thank you for your input, but our problem is not solved using this. Actaully the data we get , we don’t have a control over it, ex - for given data and converting to json or any other approach we will have escaping characters throwing errors - 
                "max_age": 604800
            }","Report-To":"{
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=tqd
                "completed": false
            }"

Comment: In what format are you receiving that data? Is it a Jackson `JsonNode`, or a Java `List`/`Map`?

Comment: Java map with which may contain data in Json format as children