# Unable to iterate through JSON in Netsuite Advanced PDF

Tags: netsuite

I encounter an issue when attempting to access the JSON data stored within the Long Text custom body field on a Netsuite transaction and then trying to iterate through it in an Advanced PDF.

When I am providing the JSON to the variable in the template and fetching the data it is working fine but when I am assigning the data from the field to a variable error is thrown

Error: For "#list" list source: Expected a sequence or collection, but this has evaluated to a hash+string
The error has occurred when the below code is used in Advanced PDF

```
<#assign abc=record.custbodytest["2"]>
     <table>
       <#list abc as x>
       <tr><td>
        ${x.vendor}
       </td></tr>
      </#list>
  </table>
```

But it is working fine when the below code is used

```
<#assign abc=[{
    "vendor": "test,
    "item": "test",
    "description": "",
    "uom": "",
    "qty": "1"
},{
    "vendor": ,
    "item": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "uom": "",
    "qty": "2"
}] >
     <table>
       <#list abc as x>
       <tr><td>
        ${x.vendor}
       </td></tr>
      </#list>
  </table>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087436/freemarker-parse-a-string-as-json.  Does that help?

Comment: No I have checked that